# How to get original image size by using Glide on Android?

Tags: android, android-glide

I am loading images from dynamic sources and loading them in my app. However sometimes the images are so small and looks bad in my app. What I want to do is get image size and if it is smaller than 5x5, don't show the ImageView at all.

How to achieve this?

When I use sizeReadyCallback, it returns the size of ImageView instead of image. When I use request listener it returns 0,0.

```
Glide.with(getContext()).load(imageUrl).listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
            //This returns 0,0
            Log.e("TAG","_width: " + resource.getBounds().width() + " _height:" +resource.getBounds().height());
            return false;
        }
    }).into(ivImage).getSize(new SizeReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSizeReady(int width, int height) {
            //This returns size of imageview.
            Log.e("TAG","width: " + width + " height: " + height);
        }
    });
```

Comment: if u getting Image via web services (i.e from `JSON`)  than this will be also getting from web side

Comment: No I am getting from an url as you can see.

Comment: yaa but from where are u getting this URL bro
?

Comment: im talking about `load(imageUrl)` of imageUrl

Comment: ok that's a static URL for e.g `imageUrl = fromwhere/abc.jpg`

Comment: This url for example, I am getting url from service but not the sizes.
https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/hWQlbb8YLxHLdmhTZ.d0BQ--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjtzbT0xO2ZpPWZpbGw7dz04NDtoPTg0O2lsPXBsYW5l/http://l.yimg.com/os/creatr-images/GLB/2017-10-19/ad133d80-b506-11e7-99c7-699637b0f57c_b54b43c0-a396-11e7-8ccc-2b9b829b86a0_headshot_oath.jpg

Comment: that's why  i already told u that put height and width in to your service, means that image's height and width count from your web side

Comment: that's why i already told u that put height and width in to your service, means that image's height and width count from your web side

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to service so I only have the url to work with.

Comment: how about: `.override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)`?

Answer (score 14):

Update:

A better solution has been provided by @TWiStErRob in comments:
[better solution](http://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/781#issuecomment-160953996)

---

For Glide v4:

```
Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext())
     .asBitmap()
     .load(path)
     .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
         @Override
         public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap,
                                     Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
             int w = bitmap.getWidth();
             int h = bitmap.getHeight()
             mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         }
     });
```

The point is getting the bitmap before set into an `ImageView`.

Comment: Not good, since you'll assign original resolution of bitmap into ImageView, wasting memory and getting uglier result because you override Glide's quality resolution downscaling. And it's also slower since you don't utilize Glide's cache of smaller-resolution image..

Comment: @PointerNull I am facing native OOM exceptions on some devices because of this pattern written in the answer. So it is true that this way is ugly and memory aggressive. The question is, what is the alternative to this method?!

Comment: I wrote an extensive solution here: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/781#issuecomment-160953996 also describing how this is can achieved efficiently. I explicitly mention this solution as being bad since it decodes the whole image, instead of the first 100-ish bytes.

Answer (score 7):

This question is old, but I stumbled across similar scenario where I needed to check for the original image size. After some digging I found [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/781) thread on Github which has the solution.

I will copy the latest (glide v4) [solution](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/781#issuecomment-348386777) written by pandasys.

This code is Kotlin but Java folks should have no trouble. The code to do the load would look something like:

```
Glide.with(activity)
 .`as`(Size2::class.java)
 .apply(sizeOptions)
 .load(uri)
 .into(object : SimpleTarget<Size2>() {
   override fun onResourceReady(size: Size2, glideAnimation: Transition<in Size2>) {
     imageToSizeMap.put(image, size)
     holder.albumArtDescription.text = size.toString()
   }

   override fun onLoadFailed(errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
     imageToSizeMap.put(image, Size2(-1, -1))
     holder.albumArtDescription.setText(R.string.Unknown)
   }
 })
```

The resusable options are:

```
private val sizeOptions by lazy {
RequestOptions()
    .skipMemoryCache(true)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)}
```

My size class is approximately:

```
data class Size2(val width: Int, val height: Int) : Parcelable {
  companion object {
    @JvmField val CREATOR = createParcel { Size2(it) }
  }

  private constructor(parcelIn: Parcel) : this(parcelIn.readInt(), parcelIn.readInt())

  override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    dest.writeInt(width)
    dest.writeInt(height)
  }

  override fun describeContents() = 0

  override fun toString(): String = "$width x $height"

}
```

Here's the relevant part of my AppGlideModule

```
 class BitmapSizeDecoder : ResourceDecoder<File, BitmapFactory.Options> {
  @Throws(IOException::class)
  override fun handles(file: File, options: Options): Boolean {
    return true
  }

  override fun decode(file: File, width: Int, height: Int, options: Options): Resource<BitmapFactory.Options>? {
    val bmOptions: BitmapFactory.Options = BitmapFactory.Options()
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath, bmOptions)
    return SimpleResource(bmOptions)
  }
}:




override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
            registry.prepend(File::class.java, BitmapFactory.Options::class.java, BitmapSizeDecoder())
            registry.register(BitmapFactory.Options::class.java, Size2::class.java, OptionsSizeResourceTranscoder())


class OptionsSizeResourceTranscoder : ResourceTranscoder<BitmapFactory.Options, Size2> {
  override fun transcode(resource: Resource<BitmapFactory.Options>, options: Options): Resource<Size2> {
    val bmOptions = resource.get()
    val size = Size2(bmOptions.outWidth, bmOptions.outHeight)
    return SimpleResource(size)
  }
}
```

So back to the original question, `onResourceReady` callback you can check for the width and height and decide what whether you show the image or not

Answer (score 2):

This hacky(in fact not) variant works as intended. As the `targetView`(which is the parameter for `.into()`) is not specified in this sequence and `.preload()` is called, the image is not resized up to the ImageView dimensions or the additional `scaleType`. You get the raw image with its original sizes, which then is set as the `ImageView`'s source.

```
val imageView = view.findViewById(...)

Glide
.with(context)
.load(imageURL)
.addListener(object: RequestListener<Drawable> {
   override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean) =
      false

   override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
      resource?.let {
         val width = resource.intrinsicWidth
         val height = resource.intrinsicHeight
         //use these sizes whatever needed for
         imageView.setImageDrawable(resource)
      }
      return false
   }
})
.preload()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     Glide.with(this)
            .asFile()
            .load("your path url image")
            .into(new SimpleTarget<File>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull File resource, @Nullable 
                    Transition<? super File> transition) {
                    fab_raw.setLabelText(""+resource.length());
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one: i not sure about this but you will do this :

```
Glide.with(this).load(uri).into(imageView).getSize(new SizeReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSizeReady(int width, int height) {
        //before you load image LOG height and width that u actually got?
        mEditDeskLayout.setImageSize(width,height);
    }
});
```

Comment: This returns size of imageview.

Answer (score -2):

```
Layout code:
    <ImageView
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible" />


     Glide.with(context).load(imgpth).placeholder(R.drawable.bg_loading)
                                .error(R.drawable.bg_loading).into(imageProdctBanner).getSize(new SizeReadyCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSizeReady(int width, int height) {
                                Log.e("width","wdthheight "+width+"  :  "+height);
                                //before you load image LOG height and width that u actually got?
                               // mEditDeskLayout.setImageSize(width,height);
                            }
                        });
working perfect its getting image original size.
Happy coding...
```