# How to set edittext background(setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)) when image is from server?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-glide

I want to set an image which is from server as background of my editText.

It is easy to set background image when the image is from **@drawable** `edit_text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);`

I'm using that to set the image from server:

```
Glide.with(img_1)
            .load(API_BASE_URL+"img/post_wall_background_1.jpg")
            .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(new RoundedCorners(15)))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.shadow)
            .into(img_1);
```

When user click on that image, I want to set it as the brackground of my editText.

How could I do that ?

I googled for hours but can not find anything about that.

AS suggested by @vikas kumar I tried that:

```
Glide.with(img_1)
            .load(API_BASE_URL+"img/post_wall_background_1.jpg")
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    new_post_edit_text.setBackground(resource);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(img_1);
```

but not work.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Use [BitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable) with [View#setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Glide to download the drawable/bitmap and use that drawble/bitmap to set the background

```
Glide.with(img_1)
    .load(API_BASE_URL+"img/post_wall_background_1.jpg")
    .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(Exception e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return false; // important to return false so the error placeholder can be placed
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
            edit_text.setBackgroundDrawable(resource);
            return false;
        }
    })
    .into(img_1);
```

Comment: Is the onResourceReady is getting called

Comment: no I have put a Toast message inside it but not Toast

Comment: Try to debug it and see where it's coming, check onFailed also if the url is correct etc.

Comment: It works fine but the setBackgroundDrawable is now depreticated. When I replace it by setBackgroundResource. It shows error. Again thanks.

Comment: Try to use setBackground() then

Comment: You saved my day. be blessed.

Comment: No problem we all go through this. Just upvote it so that others can also find it helpful.

Comment: Sorry to be back here. I have found a great problem. the **new_post_edit_text.setBackground(resource);** set a blur image (bad quality image). Any Idea ? When I use the same image something like that `new_post_edit_text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);` quality is fine. I think the problem is from the glide side.

Comment: its because the glide is giving you smaller version cache version of the image follow this thread on how to get full size image concept is same which you have applied above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827015/how-to-get-original-image-size-by-using-glide-on-android

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better solution here:

```
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load("tools/img/fsfdfg.jpg")
                            .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
                            .into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, 
@Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                                    new_post_text_view.setBackground(resource);
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {}
                            });
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.