# Android how to get image width and height from URL?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get the width and height from the API URL without download the image.

Comment: If you use Glide, your question has been answered here:

  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48554994/11037116

Answer (score 3):

```
Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext())
 .asBitmap()
 .load(path)
 .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
     @Override
     public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap,
                                 Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
         int w = bitmap.getWidth();
         int h = bitmap.getHeight()
        // mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     }
 });
```

Comment: And this does not download the image file? Well it does.